# In Doxygen with php, how to hide sql queries, variable assignment/definition and sensitive information?

Tags: php, doxygen

I am new to Doxygen. I am trying to use Doxygen to document a small php project. I just don't want to see this in the documentation

```
$query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $db_database"
```

There are many variables in the documentation that I would like to keep there definition/assignment private such as the example above or the $db_database variable for an example.

How to hide variables from included files?

I tried

```
/** \cond */
...
/** \endcond */
```

It just makes the php file really ugly...

Comment: There is no point. All your PHP code is supposed to be sensitive info.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES` to `0` in the config file or add `\hideinitializer` to the variable's documentation if you want to do this for specific variables only.